# Go app Dockerfile always downloads the modules on restart

Tags: docker, go, docker-compose

I've written an application using `Go` language and created a `Dockerfile` for it as follows. The problem is every time I restart the docker container, all the modules are being downloaded again.

```
FROM golang:1.15-alpine
WORKDIR /my-app
COPY . .
RUN go run main.go
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6):

Docker will cache each layer and use them if they are identical with the previous run. The problem with your `Dockerfile` is that you're not adding a layer for downloading modules and you're not building your application (You are running it every time). I assume that you're using `go` modules for your dependencies, so here is the fix for your `Dockerfile`

```
FROM golang:1.15-alpine
WORKDIR /my-app
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download
COPY . .
RUN go build -i -o ./build/my-app
ENTRYPOINT ["./build/my-app"]
```

With this `Dockerfile` the download process is going to cache and reused on each restart (unless you change the dependencies).

Comment: What in the changes causes Docker to not redownload? Adding RUN go mod download does not prevent redownloading unfortunately.

Comment: If your `go.mod` and `go.sum` does not change compared to the previous run, then it will be skipped